# Incorrect time but right date

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have a javascript for the current time and date. The time however is list as 7 hours ahead. How do I fix that? When you see the working website it should display a message as well as the current time and the date. However, the hour is off by about 7 hours ahead. The date and message matches the display time but it is not current. I do not understand hoe to fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

    var dateObject = new Date();
    var greeting = " ";
    var curTime = " ";
    var minuteValue = dateObject.getMinutes();
    var hourValue = dateObject.getHours();

    if (minuteValue < 10)
    minuteValue = "0" + minuteValue;
    if (hourValue < 12) {
    greeting = "<p> Good morning! "
    curTime = hourValue + ":" + minuteValue + " AM ";
    }
    else if (hourValue == 12) {
    greeting = "<p> Good afternoon! ";
    curTime = hourValue + ":" + minuteValue + " PM ";
    }
    else if (hourValue < 17) {
    greeting = "<p> Good afternoon! "
    curTime = (hourValue-12) + ":" + minuteValue + " PM "
    }
    else {
    greeting = "<p>Good evening! "
    curTime = (hourValue-12) + ":" + minuteValue + " PM "
    }

    var dayArray = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    var monthArray = new Array("January", "February",
    "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
    "September", "October", "November", "December");


    var day = dateObject.getDay();
    var month = dateObject.getMonth();

    document.write("<p>" + greeting + " It is " + curTime
    + " on " + dayArray[day] + "," + monthArray[month]
    + "" + dateObject.getDate() + ","        + dateObject.getFullYear()
    + ".</p>");
```

Comment: shows correct time and date for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nCUtj/, is your clock off or using a different timezone than it should be?

Comment: @PatrickEvans fiddle looks correct for me too.  I imagine it has something to do with the timezone offset, i.e. check `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Same here, accurate date and time.